# Connection String in App.config file to connect to EC2 SQL Server 2008 R2 from local computer

Tags: c#, xml, amazon-ec2, connection-string

My code is still in development so when I run it it is on my local computer, but the database I am using is on an instance in EC2. I am having issues connecting to the data base. I am unsure of what the server name should be, i think. Does anyone know how to connect to a SQL server on EC2, or how to configure the connection string in the App.config file.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name ="ConnectionString"
     connectionString="server=000.000.000.000\EC2SQLEXPRESS;UID=UserID;PWD=xxxxxxxxxx;database=DBName"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the DB from EC2 you will need to use it's public DNS name.  You can find this on the Instance details page.

Bear in mind that if you Stop the instance and restart it that public DNS name will change.  So you really should use an Elastic IP, associate it with your instance and have a normal public DNS name that points to the elastic IP.  This way you won't have to change your configuration info if you have to stop the instance.

Also, you will need to make sure the security group the database server is in has the desired port open.  For SQL server the standard port is 1433.

---

FYI - It is generally considered bad practice for a database server to be directly accessible on the Internet.  Instead you should have at least a web services layer in between you and the database that exposes ONLY the functionality you need.

However, if that isn't feasible, then at bare minimum you should move SQL server to a different port and expose that through your security group settings.  This doesn't actually increase your security (it's just obscuring the port) however most script attacks only target the standard SQL server ports like 1433.  So, it would help reduce the number of attacks you'll see.

Comment: @CalvinBlount: Did you miss a dot in your server address?  BTW, delete that comment.  Some people on here are not your friends...;)

Comment: Ok, deleted, thank you. The server address was a dud anyway, but I put something in there to give you an idea of what I had. I have gone through all the settings I can think of, I have to be missing something. This is for a class project, simple interopearable web services. This service will hit the DB to retrieve info about passengers, bookings, for flights when exposed to the client. My credentials are good, cause I can log on to the DB while in the instance using the computer name, but I guess I am having issues remotely connecting to it.

Comment: @CalvinBlount: Grab a copy of Management Studio to install locally.  Try to connect that way.  I'm guessing that your sql server configuration isn't configured to allow TCP/IP connections.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it to connect FINALLY!!! I just needed to use the Elastic IP address no "\EC2SQLEXPRESS" after it. I'm an idiot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you haven't enabled access through the AWS Firewall. Here's a good troubleshooting guide: https://serverfault.com/questions/165952/connecting-to-mssql-on-ec2-from-local